# How to use Group By in SQL for repetitive Column

Tags: sql, database

I need to group by SQL rows for repetitive columns. Below is the sample of my existing table: TableA

| LogId | ProcessInstanceId | Username | ActionDatetime | ActionDatetime | Activityname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 588,324 | COB-0000024750-process | nikhil | 4/27/2023 1:56:47 PM | 4/27/2023 1:56:47 PM | Branch_Maker |
| 588,325 | COB-0000024750-process | nikhil | 4/27/2023 1:56:47 PM | 4/27/2023 1:56:47 PM | Branch_Maker |
| 588,341 | COB-0000024750-process | ahmed1 | 4/27/2023 2:12:35 PM | 4/27/2023 2:12:35 PM | Branch_Maker |
| 588,342 | COB-0000024750-process | ahmed | 4/27/2023 2:12:35 PM | 4/27/2023 2:12:35 PM | Branch_Maker |
| 588,349 | COB-0000024750-process | zaghloul | 4/27/2023 2:12:56 PM | 4/27/2023 2:12:56 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 588,354 | COB-0000024750-process | mahmoud | 4/27/2023 2:14:23 PM | 4/27/2023 2:14:23 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 588,365 | COB-0000024750-process | yasro | 4/27/2023 3:11:54 PM | 4/27/2023 3:11:54 PM | Director |
| 588,366 | COB-0000024750-process | nikhil | 4/27/2023 3:11:54 PM | 4/27/2023 3:11:54 PM | Director |
| 588,369 | COB-0000024750-process | dina | 4/27/2023 3:14:10 PM | 4/27/2023 3:14:10 PM | Director |
| 588,374 | COB-0000024750-process | daniel | 4/27/2023 3:14:50 PM | 4/27/2023 3:14:50 PM | Compliance_Review |
| 588,378 | COB-0000024750-process | rocky | 4/27/2023 3:17:25 PM | 4/27/2023 3:17:25 PM | Compliance_Review |
| 588,385 | COB-0000024750-process | ricky | 4/27/2023 3:17:59 PM | 4/27/2023 3:17:59 PM | Branch_Maker_Correction |
| 588,386 | COB-0000024750-process | nikhil | 4/27/2023 3:17:59 PM | 4/27/2023 3:17:59 PM | Branch_Maker_Correction |
| 588,389 | COB-0000024750-process | dodge | 4/27/2023 3:19:37 PM | 4/27/2023 3:19:37 PM | Branch_Maker_Correction |
| 588,395 | COB-0000024750-process | seoul | 4/27/2023 3:19:55 PM | 4/27/2023 3:19:55 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 588,396 | COB-0000024750-process | nikhil | 4/27/2023 3:19:55 PM | 4/27/2023 3:19:55 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 588,408 | COB-0000024750-process | nikhil | 4/27/2023 3:21:42 PM | 4/27/2023 3:21:42 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 588,409 | COB-0000024750-process | zinne | 4/27/2023 3:21:42 PM | 4/27/2023 3:21:42 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 588,413 | COB-0000024750-process | nikhil | 4/27/2023 3:22:14 PM | 4/27/2023 3:22:14 PM | AMC_Verify |
| 588,417 | COB-0000024750-process | rohan | 4/27/2023 3:24:06 PM | 4/27/2023 3:24:06 PM | AMC_Verify |

As you can see The Column Activity name is repeating and also the same Actitity name appears after certain interval, I need to calculate minimum and maximum of ActiondateTime based on specific ActivityName considering only the the last ActionDatetime for the given ActivityName, below is the needed required output:

| processinstanceid | Branch_Maker_User | Branch_MakerTAT | Branch_Checker_User | Branch_CheckerTAT | Branch_Maker_Correction_User | Branch_Maker_CorrectionTAT | Excellency_RM_User | Excellency_RMTAT | Excellency_RM_Checker_User | Excellency_RM_CheckerTAT | Excellency_RM_Correction_User | Excellency_RM_CorrectionTAT | Wholesale_RM_User | Wholesale_RMTAT | Wholesale_RM_Checker_User | Wholesale_RM_CheckerTAT | Wholesale_RM_Correction_User | Wholesale_RM_CorrectionTAT | Director_User | DirectorTAT | Compliance_FATCA_User | Compliance_FATCATAT | Compliance_Indicator_User | Compliance_IndicatorTAT | Compliance_Review_User | Compliance_ReviewTAT | AMC_Checker_User | AMC_CheckerTAT | AMC_Verify_User | AMC_VerifyTAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COB-0000024750-process | ahmed | 16 | mahmoud | 69 | dodge | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | dina | 3 |  |  |  |  | rocky | 3 |  |  | rohan | 2 |
| COB-0000024750-process |  |  | zinnie | 69 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

As per the TableA output, Branch Checker is appearing twice so two rows are appearing.
TAT column in desired output is simple the difference between the actiondatetime once the case reach any Specific Activityname and the last Actiondatetime on the specific ActivityName, in my example its just a dummy data for TAT.

For Eg: Here for ActivityName Branch_Maker case reached at 4/27/2023 1:56:47 PM while exited at 4/27/2023 2:12:35 PM, and we need to consider only the last username who exited the case in the desired output. For Branch Maker last user is ahmed so its name to come in the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first post and I'm new to stackoverflow's features.
I'll post my solution as I understand it here without further explanation. It uses Windows Functions and Unpivot.
There is still one restriction: There must always be 2 lines per ProcessInstanceId and Activityname.

Sorry but I can't put it better in stackoverflow yet.

```
WITH t AS ( -- Create the Table
SELECT * 
FROM ( VALUES               
      ('588,324', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'nikhil     ', '1:56:47 PM', 'Branch_Maker')
    , ('588,325', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'nikhil     ', '1:56:47 PM', 'Branch_Maker')
    , ('588,341', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'ahmed1     ', '2:12:35 PM', 'Branch_Maker')
    , ('588,342', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'ahmed      ', '2:12:35 PM', 'Branch_Maker')
    , ('588,349', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'zaghloul   ', '2:12:56 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('588,354', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'mahmoud    ', '2:14:23 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('588,365', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'yasro      ', '3:11:54 PM', 'Director')
    , ('588,366', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'nikhil     ', '3:11:54 PM', 'Director')
    , ('588,369', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'dina       ', '3:14:10 PM', 'Director')
    , ('588,374', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'daniel     ', '3:14:50 PM', 'Compliance_Review')
    , ('588,378', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'rocky      ', '3:17:25 PM', 'Compliance_Review')
    , ('588,385', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'ricky      ', '3:17:59 PM', 'Branch_Maker_Correction')
    , ('588,386', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'nikhil     ', '3:17:59 PM', 'Branch_Maker_Correction')
    , ('588,389', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'dodge      ', '3:19:37 PM', 'Branch_Maker_Correction')
    , ('588,395', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'seoul      ', '3:19:55 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('588,396', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'nikhil     ', '3:19:55 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('588,408', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'nikhil     ', '3:21:42 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('588,409', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'zinne      ', '3:21:42 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('588,413', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'nikhil     ', '3:22:14 PM', 'AMC_Verify')
    , ('588,417', 'COB-0000024750-process', 'rohan      ', '3:24:06 PM', 'AMC_Verify')

    , ('589,341', 'COB-0000024760-Process', 'georg      ', '2:10:35 PM', 'Branch_Maker')
    , ('589,341', 'COB-0000024760-Process', 'georg      ', '2:12:35 PM', 'Branch_Maker')
    , ('589,395', 'COB-0000024760-Process', 'seoul      ', '3:19:55 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('589,396', 'COB-0000024760-Process', 'nikhil     ', '3:19:55 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('589,408', 'COB-0000024760-Process', 'nikhil     ', '3:21:42 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('589,409', 'COB-0000024760-Process', 'zinne      ', '3:21:42 PM', 'Branch_Checker')
    , ('589,413', 'COB-0000024760-Process', 'nikhil     ', '3:22:14 PM', 'AMC_Verify')
    , ('589,417', 'COB-0000024760-Process', 'rohan      ', '3:24:06 PM', 'AMC_Verify')
    ) AS t (LogId, ProcessInstanceId, Username, ActionDatetime, Activityname)
)
, t2 AS ( -- For each row, determine the ones before and after
SELECT *
    , LAG(Activityname, 1, 'BEGINN') OVER (ORDER BY LogId) AS LagActivityname
    , LEAD(Activityname, 1, 'ENDE') OVER (ORDER BY LogId) AS LeadActivityname
FROM t
)
, t3 AS ( -- Determine only the first and last row of a block 
SELECT *
    , LAG(t2.ActionDatetime, 1, t2.ActionDatetime) OVER (ORDER BY LogId) AS StartDateTime2
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.LogId) AS Nr21
FROM t2
WHERE (t2.Activityname<>t2.LagActivityname OR t2.Activityname<>t2.LeadActivityname)
)
, t4 AS ( -- nmuber the line of each block
SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ProcessInstanceId, t.ActivityName ORDER BY t.LogId) AS Nr1
    , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.StartDateTime2, t.ActionDatetime) AS Minuten
FROM t3 AS t
WHERE t.Activityname=t.LagActivityname
) 
, t5 AS (
SELECT t.ProcessInstanceId, t.Username AS ColValue, t.Activityname, t.Nr1--, t.Nr2 
FROM t4 AS t
UNION 
SELECT t.ProcessInstanceId, CAST(t.Minuten AS VARCHAR(5)) AS ColValue, t.Activityname+'TAT', t.Nr1--, t.Nr2 
FROM t4 AS t
)
SELECT PivotTable.ProcessInstanceId, Nr1
    , [Branch_Maker], [Branch_MakerTAT], [Branch_Checker], [Branch_CheckerTAT], [Director], [DirectorTAT]
    , [Compliance_Review], [Compliance_ReviewTAT], [Branch_Maker_Correction], [Branch_Maker_CorrectionTAT]
    , [AMC_Verify], [AMC_VerifyTAT]
FROM (SELECT t.ProcessInstanceId, t.Activityname, t.ColValue, t.Nr1
      FROM t5 AS t
      ) AS s
      PIVOT
      ( MAX(ColValue) 
        FOR Activityname IN ([Branch_Maker], [Branch_MakerTAT], [Branch_Checker], [Branch_CheckerTAT], [Director], [DirectorTAT]
                           , [Compliance_Review], [Compliance_ReviewTAT], [Branch_Maker_Correction], [Branch_Maker_CorrectionTAT]
                           , [AMC_Verify], [AMC_VerifyTAT])
      ) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY ProcessInstanceId, Nr1;
```

Comment: Hi @Gerge Martin, your response almost solved my issue. suppose if I have a custom function [dbo].getWorkingMinuteDiff which calculate the difference between two actiondatetime, how we can implement the given function in your above response. Also if in case I need to append sum of total Time difference at the end of each row, how we can achieve the same.